# My KeyListener does not work

Tags: java, keyevent

Please help me guys. I just can't run the KeyListener. But I have added everything you need (i think). I really have no idea what's wrong with this code. I added a Key Listener, implemented a key listener and included all classes so what did I forgot? :/

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

/******Key classes are included*********/
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/********Key listener is Implemented********/
public class Game extends JPanel implements KeyListener,Runnable
{

    JPanel m_mainPanel;
    Thread moveBall = new Thread();
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);

    int radius = 50;

    int posx = 400;
    int posy = 400;

    int RectPosX = 10;
    int RectPosY = 400;

    int velocityX = 0;
    int velocityY = 0;

    //Konstruktor
    public Game(JPanel mainPanel) {
        m_mainPanel = mainPanel;
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        JPanel north_panel = new JPanel();
        north_panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        /**********I didn't forget this********/
        this.addKeyListener(this);


        /*******Focus is set**********/
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

        add(north_panel);

    }

    //Painting rectangle
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(RectPosX, RectPosY, radius, radius);
    }



    //the key event wich isn't called
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Key pressed");

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            velocityY = 10;
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            velocityY = -10;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        while(true)
        {
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What has the focus? I'll bet you 5 dollars it's the JFrame instead of the JPanel. Either add the KeyListener to the JFrame, or give focus to the JPanel.

Comment: How can I change the focus? edit: The JFrame has no KeyListener implemented

Comment: Google is your friend, but requestFocusInWindow() is a good place to start.

Comment: I got the focus request denied :/

Answer (score -1):

Here's a little example MCVE:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class Main extends JPanel{


    public Main(){
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Typed: " + e.getKeyChar());
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Pressed: " + e.getKeyChar());
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Released: " + e.getKeyChar());
            }

        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Main());
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This program exhibits the same problem you're having: the key listener is never called! This is because the **focus** is on the JFrame, not the JPanel.

To change this, you have to make the JPanel **focusable**. You do this by simply calling the setFocusable() method. Now your JPanel will have the focus:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class Main extends JPanel{


    public Main(){
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Typed: " + e.getKeyChar());
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Pressed: " + e.getKeyChar());
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Released: " + e.getKeyChar());
            }

        });

        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Main());
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

More complicated programs might require the requestFocusInWindow() function. Or you might want to look into using KeyBindings instead. But your main problem is caused by focus issues.

Comment: I ialready have the set focusable implemented in the constructor:

Comment: There's the MCVE:

Game Class: http://pastebin.com/bPFsjVC
Menu Class; http://pastebin.com/CjUFPHVw
Menu Item Class: http://pastebin.com/XZkumNgB
Menu Buttons Class: http://pastebin.com/Zx1Y86gm